# Visual Studio GoToAll opening in new window instead of corner

Tags: visual-studio

While using visual studio, when I use the Go To All feature either through Edit -> Go To -> Go To All or through Ctrl+T, it opens up a new window instead of opening in the top righthand corner like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to?view=vs-2022.

When I use Ctrl+T it opens in a separate window
[image: gotoall opening a separate window]

I've tried resetting the keyboard shortcut and using Window -> Reset Window Layout, but it's no use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76458047/why-is-visual-studio-2022-go-to-all-or-search-feature-dialogs-not-showing-all