# Why is Visual Studio 2022 "go to all" or search feature dialogs not showing all of a sudden?

Tags: visual-studio

For years I have been using the mapped Ctrl+T 'Go To All' shortcut to search for Classes, Methods and Properties in Visual Studio with a great deal of success.

A week or so ago (perhaps after an update - I'm not sure as I have auto updates on) it stopped working. Even when I manually click on the 'Search' tool (or use the default Ctrl + Q shortcut); I get nothing. No popup dialog appears.

I now can't seem to get the feature back. What's going on?

I have tried the following:

- Rebooted Visual Studio
- Rebooted the machine
- Remapped the Ctrl+T 'GoToAll' shortcut

Any other ideas/suggestions would be useful as I am quite reliant on the feature for productivity.

Worth mentioning that I haven't raised a bug or asked Microsoft yet - I was wondering if anyone else had this issue before I go ahead and do that.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.6.2

**Edit: I have now raised a ticket with Microsoft:** https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/GoToAll-CtrlT-stopped-working--/10476093

Comment: Seems to be fixed with update 17.6.4.

Comment: Not for me sadly - I have updated to that version and still have this issue :-(

Comment: This bug was fixed for me in 17.7.4 so I recommend upgrading for those experiencing this issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those on Visual Studio versions < 17.7.4; I would recommend upgrading. If you don't want to upgrade then follow the instructions below as a workaround:

- Turn off the 'New Visual Studio Search experience' feature in Debug->Options->Environment->Preview Features
- Restart Visual Studio

[image]

Ctrl+T now works as expected - the GoToAll popup appears

Comment: thank god, finally. why would they disable the quick action to go to a line number e.g `: 2134` goes to line 2134 in the current document. yet another reason to just use vim ffs

Comment: The new Search experience couldn't find half my files for some reason in (17.7.6). Disabling it works for now.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth...

I'm having the same problem on VS Pro 2022 (64-bit) 17.6.3,

BUT...
If I select some text, hit Ctrl-T, wait a few seconds, then hit Enter, I get navigated to what I presume would have been the first search result.

So it seems like the problem is that the GoTo All dialog is getting activated but is not visible.  The "Goto All" search apparently is happening but invisibly.

This makes part of the functionality possible but not the ability to see and choose from the search results.

(In some very recent update there was a preview window added to the Ctrl-, results listing which may have been a nice addition.  But a few days later, it does nothing.  Ctrl-T does "something" Ctrl- does nothing, like for you, even after I tried remapping the Goto All.)

Hope that helps at least a little until there is a fix.

---

...Update:  After switching back to a different multi-monitor setup, the Ctrl-T dialog shows up again.  It probably was popping up off screen or near off-screen with the other monitor setup.

### `If that is happening for you, here's the how to get it back:`
After activating the window with Ctrl-T,
Alt-<space> M
then use the mouse or arrow keys to move that window back on your screen.

Comment: Hit Ctrl-T, type your search term (blindly), wait a few seconds, then hit Enter ... also navigates.

Comment: Thanks for that - good to know someone else is experiencing this issue

Answer (score 0):

GaryGI's answer got me on the right path. He writes:

> **If that is happening for you, here's the how to get it back: After activating the window with Ctrl-T, Alt- M then use the mouse or arrow keys to move that window back on your screen.**

---

I DID test this but moving the window didn't work in my case. BUT, there's also the "Maximize" option (Alt- X) and this would make the window visible again!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34896283)